# After upgrade to django 1.8 runserver hangs at startup

Tags: python, django

I'm upgrading to django 1.8 from 1.4. After upgrade runserver works fine without my applications. But when I adds one of them to installed_apps it just hangs at startup.
Command:

```
C:\Programs\Python27\python.exe C:/Projects/prj/django/django_projects/manage.py runserver localhost:8080 --verbosity=3
```

and no output is provided (even when I use verbosity=3). 
Here is a screenshot of procmon set up for python.exe http://clip2net.com/s/3pQPHSb
Is there any ways to debug why it hangs?

```
10:39:23.9166574 PM python.exe  7420    QueryDirectory  C:\Programs\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\logging   NO SUCH FILE    Filter: logging
10:39:23.9168061 PM python.exe  7420    CreateFile  C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\logging.pyd   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
10:39:23.9169126 PM python.exe  7420    CreateFile  C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\logging.py    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
10:39:23.9170179 PM python.exe  7420    CreateFile  C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\logging.pyw   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
10:39:23.9171225 PM python.exe  7420    CreateFile  C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\logging.pyc   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
10:39:24.0008918 PM python.exe  7420    CreateFile  C:\Programs\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django_loginas-0.1.5-py2.7.egg-info  SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
10:39:24.0009480 PM python.exe  7420    QueryBasicInformationFile   C:\Programs\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django_loginas-0.1.5-py2.7.egg-info  SUCCESS CreationTime: 3/21/2015 12:21:25 PM, LastAccessTime: 3/21/2015 12:21:26 PM, LastWriteTime: 3/21/2015 12:21:26 PM, ChangeTime: 3/21/2015 12:21:26 PM, FileAttributes: D
10:39:24.0009873 PM python.exe  7420    CloseFile   C:\Programs\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django_loginas-0.1.5-py2.7.egg-info  SUCCESS 
10:39:24.0201031 PM python.exe  7420    CreateFile  C:\programs\python27\lib\site-packages\django_loginas-0.1.5-py2.7.egg-info\namespace_packages.txt   NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
10:39:24.0612018 PM python.exe  7420    CreateFile  C:\Programs\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django_loginas-0.1.5-py2.7.egg-info  SUCCESS Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
10:39:24.0612568 PM python.exe  7420    QueryBasicInformationFile   C:\Programs\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django_loginas-0.1.5-py2.7.egg-info  SUCCESS CreationTime: 3/21/2015 12:21:25 PM, LastAccessTime: 3/21/2015 12:21:26 PM, LastWriteTime: 3/21/2015 12:21:26 PM, ChangeTime: 3/21/2015 12:21:26 PM, FileAttributes: D
10:39:24.0612878 PM python.exe  7420    CloseFile   C:\Programs\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django_loginas-0.1.5-py2.7.egg-info  SUCCESS 
10:39:24.3178297 PM python.exe  7420    CloseFile   C:\Programs\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\log.py  SUCCESS 
10:39:24.3292991 PM python.exe  7420    QueryDirectory  C:\Programs\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\middleware\logging    NO SUCH FILE    Filter: logging
10:39:24.3294485 PM python.exe  7420    CreateFile  C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\logging.pyd    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
10:39:24.3295557 PM python.exe  7420    CreateFile  C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\logging.py NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
10:39:24.3296610 PM python.exe  7420    CreateFile  C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\logging.pyw    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
10:39:24.3297664 PM python.exe  7420    CreateFile  C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\logging.pyc    NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
10:39:24.5965679 PM python.exe  7420    QueryDirectory  C:\Programs\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\logging NO SUCH FILE    Filter: logging
10:39:24.5967232 PM python.exe  7420    CreateFile  C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\logging.pyd NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
10:39:24.5968351 PM python.exe  7420    CreateFile  C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\logging.py  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
10:39:24.5969426 PM python.exe  7420    CreateFile  C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\logging.pyw NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
10:39:24.5970523 PM python.exe  7420    CreateFile  C:\Programs\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\logging.pyc NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, a lot has changed between those versions, so I doubt there is a simple change required. Here are some suggestions for making the upgrade path easier:

- Try running your app w/ intermediate versions to see when it starts hanging. That might give you a clue as to what needs to be changed. Also, you should start getting deprecation warnings as you increment versions.
- Try [`runserver_plus`](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/runserver_plus.html) from [`django-extensions`](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) to potentially get some more feedback.
- Take a look at [this post](https://www.seedinvest.com/labs/backend/upgrading-from-django-1-4-to-django-1-7/) about upgrading from 1.4 to 1.7.
- [Here](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TNL/Django+Upgrade+1.4+to+1.8) are some extensive notes from [the Open edX group](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform) currently in the process of upgrading several apps from 1.4 to 1.8.

Comment: thanks for you suggestions. I understand that it could be a lot of items to fix and already resolved a set of issues. But this one is a bit tricky because no debug output is provided.

Comment: @dbf Is the app that is causing the problem available for us to look at?

Comment: looks liek I solved this issue. It was an import (indirect) of the files where it was a setup for running as standalone script (with django.setup() call) - I used it for testing and forgot to remove it. It was fine for django 1.4 (where is was setup_environ), hang at 1.8 and error in 1.6 (that's how I found it). Thanks again for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. What solved it for me was:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': ':memory:',
    },
}
```

Kind regards.